# Possible to upgrade to 11.10 without the "extra applications". Like no-install-recommends?

Tags: installation, upgrade, 11.10

I am using 11.04 which I started off with a Command Line System via Alternate CD then installed apps on top. When I upgrade to 11.10 soon, isit possible to upgrade just the OS, probably with the core files (Unity etc) but without the extra apps (Office etc, unless I have them installed already)

Or do I need to installed from scratch from a 11.10 Alternate CD again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official way to upgrade Ubuntu from the command-line](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/installing-upgrading.html) is intended to work the way you want: it should only upgrade the packages you've already got on the system.

If it does install new packages, it is because some upgraded packages have new dependencies. This applies especially to the package `ubuntu-desktop`, which will depend on all the new default applications. I doubt you have `ubuntu-desktop` installed though, as you installed the server edition.

Comment: No actually I got the CLI system from Ubuntu Alternative CD, I think it should be Ubuntu Desktop

Comment: The link I shared is for Ubuntu server and works from the command-line, I've edited the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though more complicated. Interestingly thought his method can be safer if you know what you are doing (I trust you know what you are doing?).

If you have Synaptic installed (I suggest you use Synaptic for this process):

- open Synaptic
- then open software sources, and change all entries from natty to oneiric, then reload your sources.
- Manually upgrade your packages (either bit by bit, or all at once, though I suggest bit by bit).
- When you are done you will be running 11.10, should all go smoothly.

Comment: Usually I use apt-get not synaptic. So isit the same as open `/etc/apt/sources.list` then find/replace "natty" with "oneiric"? So "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted" becomes "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted"? RE "Manually upgrade your packages ... bit by bit". What do you mean by bit by bit? I think the opposite will be `apt-get upgrade?`. How do I do it bit by bit then? If I do it this way, might I be missing any files/apps required by the "updated" Ubuntu?

Comment: Also I have upgraded a Ubuntu 11.04 on Virtual Box using `update-manager -d` then removed packaged I see in Software Center I don't need, finally ran `apt-get autoremove`. That should clear up the mess right (esp. what I don't see in Software Center or those Technical Packages)? So I should now have a result similar to your upgrade method?

Comment: @jiewmeng: using `update-manager -d` and `apt-get autoremove` can work but it is not a certain method. I would suggest using something like synaptic if you can. Apt-get upgrade *can* work, but you are more likely to run into problems. So unless you have something against synaptic, I suggest you use that (trying to save you trouble here :).

Comment: I have no problems with Synaptic, just unfamiliar, how do I start? I tried Settings > Repositories, but how do i change to oneiric? Then how do i update bit by bit?

Comment: @jiewmeng: I will have to update my answer when I have more time. Until then, you can get some help in the chat room (I have to get ready for church at the moment).

Comment: This is *not* the recommended way to upgrade Ubuntu. Use `update-manager`, as it can perform some additional tasks related to cleaning old unsupported packages, and migrating to new ones safely. Also, there is practically no difference between using Synaptic and `apt-get`.